# empty output files when using gdal.vectorTranslate

Tags: javascript, node.js, gdal, dxf, ogr2ogr

Using gdal-async in nodejs, im trying to convert verctor files from geojson to dxf.

```
const dsGeoJSON2 = gdal.open('./upload2/objects.geojson'); 
const out2 = gdal.vectorTranslate('./upload2/objects.dxf', dsGeoJSON2, ['-f', 'DXF']);
```

the output file is emty, even with .kml  but when i change to gpx for example it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either explicitly close the output file:

```js
const dsGeoJSON2 = gdal.open('./upload2/objects.geojson'); 
const out2 = gdal.vectorTranslate(
  './upload2/objects.dxf',
  dsGeoJSON2,
  ['-f', 'DXF']
).close();
```

either simply quit the program.

The flushing/closing of the file runs when the GC collects the variable holding the dataset.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, thank you